# Pass a parameter from SSRS to MySQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql, ssrs, ssrs-2012

Here is the query for the dataset:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CompanyId, Company
FROM            User_Hierarchy_Mapping
WHERE           UserId = @FieldManager
```

`FieldManager` is the parameter name. It's not taking the value of the parameter.

Please help me with the syntax to pass a parameter to a MySQL query.

Comment: Take a look at `SET`!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a MySQL ODBC connector in SSRS you can't use named parameters but you should use `?` instead.

So for your query it should look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CompanyId, Company
FROM            User_Hierarchy_Mapping
WHERE           UserId = ?
```

That way you should get a parameter named `Parameter1`. If you have more than one question mark your parameters will be named `Parameter1`, `Parameter2` etc in the same order as they appear in the query.

This isn't specific to MySQL but to any ODBC connection. See [Binding Parameters ODBC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712522(v=vs.85).aspx) for reference.

Comment: How to change this to allow IN clause, I am not able to make it work for multi select for MySQL ODBC

Comment: @ZAJ you will need to concatenate it in an expression

Comment: Cheers, got it.